# clear html of element than append to that element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an object where I loop through which looks like this:

```
rules: Array(3), valid: false, condition: "AND"}
condition:"AND"
rules:Array(3)

0:field:"ImpressionShare"
id:"ImpressionShare"
operator:"greater_calculation"
type:"integer"
value:{target: "0.5", operator: "x", inputValue: "AdGroupType"}

Object
1:field:"AggregatedFields.ROIIncludingAssisted"
id:"AggregatedFields.ROIIncludingAssisted"
operator:"not_begins_with"
type:"string"
value:[]

2:field:"Impressions"
id:"Impressions"
operator:"less_or_equal_calculation"
type:"integer"
value:{target: "0.5", operator: "x", inputValue: "AdGroupType"}
```

I loop throught the rules and than through the values I want to create inputs based on the values and append them like this:

```
loadedRules.rules.forEach( function(item, index){
   var value = item.value;

   for(var i in value){

      var inputs = document.createElement("input");
      inputs.className = "form-control";

      console.log(inputs);
      console.log(value[i]);

      $(inputs).val(value[i]);

        $(`#builder-widgets_rule_${index}`).find('.rule-value-container').html('')
      $(`#builder-widgets_rule_${index}`).find('.rule-value-container').append(inputs);
   }


   console.log($(`.builder-widgets_rule_${index}`).find('.rule-value-container'));
})
```

But it only appends one element and if I do not clear it with `html('')` than it appends them all but I want to clear it first and than append

Comment: if you clear the html and then append, you will end up with only one input in each rule, right? is that what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easy: you clear the element using `.html('')` outside and before the `for` loop. This is so that you don't end up purging the content at each iteration of the `for` loop:

```
loadedRules.rules.forEach( function(item, index){
   var value = item.value;

   // Clear everything first
   $(`#builder-widgets_rule_${index}`).find('.rule-value-container').html('')

   for(var i in value){

      var inputs = document.createElement("input");
      inputs.className = "form-control";

      $(inputs).val(value[i]);

      // Append iteratively
      $(`#builder-widgets_rule_${index}`).find('.rule-value-container').append(inputs);
   }
});
```

Alternatively, you don't even need to rely on `document.createElement` to create your input, jQuery can handle that quite well itself:

```
loadedRules.rules.forEach( function(item, index){
   var value = item.value;

   // Clear everything first
   $(`#builder-widgets_rule_${index}`).find('.rule-value-container').html('');

   $.each(item.value, function(i, itemValue) {
     // Create new input element
     var $input = $('input', {
        'class': 'form-control'
     }).val(itemValue);

     // Append created input element
     $(`#builder-widgets_rule_${index}`).find('.rule-value-container').append($input);
   });
})
```

Comment: but than index is undefined because that comes with the foreach

Comment: @Sreinieren Whoops, my bad. I moved the statement two levels up. It should just sit right before the loop :)

Comment: @Pete Thanks! I've reworded my answer.